# Jquery if statement executing when it is either false or true

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement

Either if the class is the same or not, it enter the IF.

I tried checking with console log the code as above and it shows correctly true or false.

**EDIT:**
I noticed that this problem is not facing up the first time the page load, after toggling other buttons the problem shows up. Added code. (I'm using Yii2 framework, if it is relevant, but i think not).

```js
if (!$('#7D').hasClass('active') && !$('#1M').hasClass('active') && !$('#1Y').hasClass('active')) {
  $('#1M').addClass('active');
}

if (!$('#7D').hasClass('active')) {
  $('#7D').off('click').click(function() {
    $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    $('#7D').addClass('active');
  });
}

if (!$('#1M').hasClass('active')) {
  $('#1M').off('click').click(function() {
    $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    $('#1M').addClass('active');
  });
}

if (!$('#1Y').hasClass('active')) {
  $('#1Y').off('click').click(function() {
    $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    $('#1Y').addClass('active');
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="button1" class="pull-left">
      <div id="w1" class="btn-group">
        <button id="7D" class="btn">7D</button>
        <button id="1M" class="btn">1M</button>
        <button id="1Y" class="btn">1Y</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186295/discussion-on-question-by-l-antonelli-jquery-if-statement-executing-when-it-is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e){

   if($(this).hasClass('active')) return;

   $('.btn').removeClass('active');

   $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6fLb9c3/2/)

and [screencast](https://monosnap.com/file/EuUpP0nNNCIj7vpGwSmO7dV4nQJwFS) shows that it works fine:

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your if-statement is outside of your `click` event. The `if` is only checked when the code is initially ran. Once the `click` event is attached to the element it will execute when the button is clicked, regardless the code around it.

If you want to execute the click only if it is not active, you need to move the `if` inside your `click` event.

```js
if (!$('#7D').hasClass('active') && !$('#1M').hasClass('active') && !$('#1Y').hasClass('active')) {
  $('#1M').addClass('active');
}

$('#7D').off('click').click(function() {
  if (!$('#7D').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    $('#7D').addClass('active');
    console.log('added active class to #7D');
  }
});

$('#1M').off('click').click(function() {
  if (!$('#1M').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    $('#1M').addClass('active');
    console.log('added active class to #7M');
  }
});

$('#1Y').off('click').click(function() {
  if (!$('#1Y').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    $('#1Y').addClass('active');
    console.log('added active class to #7Y');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="button1" class="pull-left">
      <div id="w1" class="btn-group">
        <button id="7D" class="btn">7D</button>
        <button id="1M" class="btn">1M</button>
        <button id="1Y" class="btn">1Y</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it would also be possible to attach the click event dynamically using jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function. This way you don't need to repeat the same code for the buttons and it allows you to use exclude buttons with the class `active` dynamically.

```js
if (!$('#7D').hasClass('active') && !$('#1M').hasClass('active') && !$('#1Y').hasClass('active')) {
  $('#1M').addClass('active');
}

$('#w1').off('click').on('click', '.btn:not(.active)', function() {
  $('.btn').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  console.log('added active class to #' + this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="button1" class="pull-left">
      <div id="w1" class="btn-group">
        <button id="7D" class="btn">7D</button>
        <button id="1M" class="btn">1M</button>
        <button id="1Y" class="btn">1Y</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```